# Ubuntu Laptop WiFi working poorly

Tags: networking, wireless, dell, laptop, intel

My WiFi is constantly on two bars while in my room. I used to get full bars when I had windows installed, and I get full bars on my phone. The WiFi symbol never leaves 2 bars unless it's empty and just shows a '?' in the middle, I've been turning my WiFi off then back on again which usually fixes it the first time, if no the second, but the internet will stop working after around half an hour of use, it will either stop working and still show two bars, or it will stop working and show no bars but a '?' in the middle. My laptop never disconnects from internet automatically either, and sometimes when it stops working with two bars, it will start working if I leave it for 10 minutes or so.

**Other information**

Laptop: [Dell Inspiron 15 7000](https://www.dell.com/en-ca/shop/dell-laptops/inspiron-15-2-in-1-laptop/spd/inspiron-15-7506-2-in-1-laptop/ni157506_sb_h13be)

Ubuntu Version: 20.04.4

Install date: 15/03/22 | D/M/Y

Pictures:

[WiFi with two bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhfVH.png)

[WiFi with no bars and question mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj9fg.png)

Comment: Sounds like a driver issue. I would look a the firmware compatibility as my first guess.

Comment: BRB how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score -1):

go to "updates" or "more drivers" and activate use proprietary driver
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qs4Jp.png)

Comment: [my drivers](https://imgur.com/8Hoxips)

they don't look like yours

Comment: This is NOT applicable to anything else than the WiFi devices that work with proprietary drivers, a very small set. This kind of answer is like "take this pill, it worked for me". Better check with an actual doctor first ;)